# Inverted Regex Dilemma

Tags: regex, ruby

I've searched the forum but can't find an answer.

I'm using ruby v1.9.3 and need to invert a regex match.
for example:

```
 string = "once upon a time long ago"
    string.scan(/upon/).join
```

but:

```
    string.scan(/[^upon]/).join

==> "ce a time lg ag"
```

the individual letters of "upon" are being matched too, seemingly caused by the brackets.

Edit:
Thanks for t he quick replies all.
Sorry I dont Think I explained myself very well
what I want to do is match everything except "upon":

[Rubular example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhYN8.png)

I hope this is clearer now

Comment: `[^upon]` will match all characters other that `u` or `p` or `o` or `n`... will `string.split.reject { |s| s == "upon" }.join(" ")` solve your issue?

Comment: you can also use `sub` method to search and replace a string

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  What exactly is your question?  Is it "what do brackets do in regex?"  And---one step further--"what does the `^` char do within brackets in regex?"

Comment: No, it is not clearer. What do you mean by "match everything except..."? You are given a string of characters, not a sentence. If a string may contain substrings (sequences of characters) that you wish to extract you must identify the characteristics of the substrings of interest.  Suppose, in your example, the string were "Once upon a qupon". What is the array of strings you wish to extract? To be an effective programmer you need to be precise in your language as well as in your code.  Lastly, when you edit a question to clarify, just rewrite it; don't make it a narrative.

Comment: It is NOT possible to match a sequence of chars that is not equal to some sequence of patterns. You may only match some text that is not equal to a/some single char(s). That's why you cannot use `scan` here. Use either `gsub` or `split` with your pattern. If you do not need a whole word match use `s.split('upon').map(&:strip).join(' ')`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/97y4NT).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the word within boundaries to form the "upon" word (plus a whitespace):

```
"once upon a time long ago".gsub(/\bupon \b/, '')
# "once a time long ago"
```

Using `sub` or `gsub`, depending on the number of occurrences you can find in your string.

Comment: What if the string ends `" upon"`? `/\bupon ?\b/` would match "upone", so that's no good. Nor would `/\bupon(?= |\z)` work, as you want to match a following space, if there is one. Perhaps `/\bupon \b|\bupon\z/`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this expression might also work:

```
(?:\bupon\b\s+)|(.*?)
```

#### Test

```
re = /(?:\bupon\b\s+)|(.*?)/m
str = 'once upon a time long ago once upon a time long ago once upon a time long ago '
subst = '$1'

result = str.gsub(re, subst)

puts result
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MRk1by/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/MRk1by/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Unescaped brackets are intended to match characters.  For example, any of the following regex's would match on the string 'upon':

```
/[upon]/
/[upoXn]/
/[nopu]/
#==> upon
#==> upon
#==> upon
```

However, `^` has special meaning within brackets: it is a negation operator.

So, `/[^upon]/` is specifically not matching on any characters contained in the string 'upon'.

This is demonstrated in your example:

```
string.scan(/[^upon]/).join
#=> "ce a time lg ag"
```

If you are just looking to replace the string 'upon', then `String::gsub` (as @Sebastian Palma suggests) should do the trick.  YMMV.

Comment: Consider defining of a *character class* before giving your examples.

Comment: Fair enough.  Tried to keep the answer as "simple" as possible because the OP seems confused.  Not really sure what he is trying to solve and didn't want to devolve into a full regex tutorial (which the OP should really start with).

Comment: I just meant something like, `"[upon]"` is a *character class*, meaning that any one of the characters between the braces must be matched. By making the first character a circumflex/caret (`'^'`) none of the remaining characters can be matched.". Just a suggestion...